# Blob data type in Cassandra

Tags: c++, cassandra, blob, cql

I don't understand much about using blob data type.  I'm new in Cassandra and have just started working with Cassandra's C++ API.  Can the contents of a C++ structure be stored in Cassandra's Blob.  If yes,  then how.  For example,  to store bigint as blob we've bigintAsBlob().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a `struct`:

```
struct my_struct {
    int field1;
    double field2;
};
```

And a prepared statement (I hope you use prepared statements), you can do this:

```
my_struct s;
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[sizeof(my_struct)]);
memcpy(buffer.get(), &s, sizeof(my_struct));
cass_statement_bind_bytes(statement, index, buffer.get(), sizeof(my_struct))
```

Where `statement` is a prepared statement and index is the index of the `blob` field in your schema.
Note that your struct has to be a POD with no members relying on dynamic memory (e.g. no `char*`), otherwise this won't work. I didn't test this but I hope it helps.